Refresh rate and Color setting not showing all options in NVIDIA Control Panel
I want to change my output color format and refresh rate. I click on "Use NVIDIA color settings" under "Display" -> "Change resolution". I only see YCbCr420 available in the dropdown menu. Same for the color depth, only 8-bit is available.
Under refresh rate, the maximum is 60Hz, even though I know 120Hz should be listed (I am using a 4k 120Hz display with HDMI 2.1 cable).

Make sure you have "PC" resolution selected. "Ultra HD, HD, SD" resolutions have limited options as described in the question.
Now I see all RGB, YCbCr420, and 444 with color depth 8-12 bpc and a maximum 120 Hz refresh rate. First set the refresh rate, the available color settings are dependent on it.
